# Help needed integrating a second-order ODE with non-constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need some help solving a differential equation of the form:

$ Y''(x) -aY'(x) -2bc \times e^{-bx} Y(x) = 0 $

where a, b, c, are constants.

I am reasonably familiar with methods for solving second-order ODEs with constant coefficients but I need some help at least identifying what method to use to solve this equation.

Comment: My first thought would be Laplace transforms.

Comment: Thanks John. Could you elaborate some more on what you think could work or point me in the direction of a resource I could look at?

Comment: Or you can assume that $Y(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0} c_nx^n$, also that $e^{-bx}= \sum_{n\geq 0} (-bx)^n/n!$, plug it into the equation, find all the $c_n$'s, and try to recognize what the resulting series described. I think people call this the Frobenius Method. Doing Laplace Transforms as John suggested is probably easier.

Comment: I've never encountered an equation of that sort before. Laplace transforms was a suggestion, but I do not know if that is the correct approach. But you can find a discussion of Laplace transforms in any introduction to differential equations textbook.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{d^2Y}{dx^2} -a\frac{dY}{dx} -2bc e^{-bx} Y(x) = 0 $$
Change of variable :
$$X=e^x\quad\implies\quad \frac{dX}{dx}=X $$
$$\frac{dY}{dx}=\frac{dY}{dX}\frac{dX}{dx}=X\frac{dY}{dX}$$
$$\frac{d^2Y}{dx^2}=\frac{d\left(X\frac{dY}{dX}\right)}{dX}\frac{dX}{dx}=X\frac{d\left(X\frac{dY}{dX}\right)}{dX}=X^2\frac{d^2Y}{dX^2}+X\frac{dY}{dX}$$
$$ X^2\frac{d^2Y}{dX^2}+X\frac{dY}{dX} -aX\frac{dY}{dX} -2bc e^{-bx} Y = 0 $$
$e^{-bx}=X^{-b}$
$$ \frac{d^2Y}{dX^2}+\frac{1-a}{X}\frac{dY}{dX} -2bc X^{-b-2} Y = 0 $$
This is a generalized Bessel ODE. For solvig it see Eqs.$(3,4,5)$ in : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html